# What does NVL stand for?

Tags: oracle, functions, informix

What does `NVL` stand for? I'm talking about the Oracle and Informix (perhaps some others too) function used to filter out non NULL values from query results (similar to `COALESCE` in other databases).

Comment: An interesting comparison of NVL and COALESCE in Oracle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950084/oracle-differences-between-nvl-and-coalesce

Comment: "There is a story here, but I don't remember the names of the X3H2 [SQL standard] Committee members involved.  We came up with this function because everyone had an `NVL()` or `IFNULL()` or something in their product and we wanted a standard syntax for it. Someone else generalized it to a list, but nobody coudl come up with a name we all liked... someone pulled out a Thesaurus and started looking for a single word that nobody would use for a table name, column name or other function and that was not used in any existing product. 
You know who the winner was now [i.e. `COALESCE`]" -- Joe Celko.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Quite simply: Null VaLue

The function substitutes any NULLs in a given resultset column with the value given as the second parameter.

Comment: http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/NVL

Answer (score 10):

"Null Value Logic" according to http://www.abbreviations.com/term/157605, but most of the other references I have found support Phil's "Null Value" supposition.  I haven't found a definitive origin.

Answer (score 2):

In assembly language programming also programmers used [NVL](https://formfull.in/nvl) for Null Value Logic. So in this case also it indicates Null Value.